# Function to repeat a certain menu in C

Tags: c, function

I am new to C programming language. I want the following code to repeat the main menu after the "Transaction successful" and also store a new balance after an amount is entered.How do i go about it. Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int mainmenu, amt, balance = 0;
    printf("1.Pay \n");
    printf("2.Balance \n");
    printf("3.Transaction history \n");
    scanf("%d",&mainmenu);

    if(mainmenu == 1){
        printf("Select Amount \n");
        printf("$0.50 \n");
        printf("$1.00 \n");
        printf("$1.50 \n");
        printf("$2.00 \n");
        scanf("%d",&amt);

        if(amt == 1){
            balance = balance + 0.5;
            printf("Transaction Successful \n");

        }
        if(amt == 2){
             balance = balance + 1;
            printf("Transaction Successful \n");
        }
        if(amt == 3){
             balance = balance + 1.5;
            printf("Transaction Successful \n");
        }
        if(amt == 4){
             balance = balance + 2;
            printf("Transaction Successful \n");
        }

    }
    if(mainmenu == 2){
        printf("\n");
        printf("Balance = %d",balance,"\n");
    }
    if(mainmenu == 3){
        printf("No Transaction History At The Moment");
    }

}
```

Comment: It's called "loop". Usually a `while`-loop

Comment: One way would be to put the menu in its own function. The `main` logic would then be easier. As your project grows, put each of the menu's operations in its own function too. At each stage you can use the function's return value to drive the flow, so the program flow is not snarled up with the detail. There is a phrase I was taught: "separate **form** and **function**."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two different methods you can use. A `while` loop, or a `for` loop.

The syntax for both are like so:

```
while(condition) {
   statement(s); // execute this section of code until the condition is met
}
```

and

```
for (initilization; condition; increment){
    statement(s); // execute this section of code until the condition is met
}
```

if you want an infinite loop, you can use `TRUE` as the condition in the `while` loop like:

```
while(TRUE) {
   statement(s); // execute this section of code indefinitely
}
```

or you can leave the parameters empty in the `for` loop like so:

```
for( ; ; ){
    statement(s); // execute this section of code indefinitely
}
```

in your case, it would look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int mainmenu, amt, balance = 0;

    while(TRUE){
        printf("1.Pay \n");
        printf("2.Balance \n");
        printf("3.Transaction history \n");
        scanf("%d",&mainmenu);

        if(mainmenu == 1){
            printf("Select Amount \n");
            printf("$0.50 \n");
            printf("$1.00 \n");
            printf("$1.50 \n");
            printf("$2.00 \n");
            scanf("%d",&amt);

            if(amt == 1){
                balance = balance + 0.5;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");

            }
            if(amt == 2){
                 balance = balance + 1;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");
            }
            if(amt == 3){
                 balance = balance + 1.5;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");
            }
            if(amt == 4){
                 balance = balance + 2;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");
            }

        }
        if(mainmenu == 2){
            printf("\n");
            printf("Balance = %d",balance,"\n");
        }
        if(mainmenu == 3){
            printf("No Transaction History At The Moment");
        }

    }
}
```

or:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int mainmenu, amt, balance = 0;

    for( ; ; ){
        printf("1.Pay \n");
        printf("2.Balance \n");
        printf("3.Transaction history \n");
        scanf("%d",&mainmenu);

        if(mainmenu == 1){
            printf("Select Amount \n");
            printf("$0.50 \n");
            printf("$1.00 \n");
            printf("$1.50 \n");
            printf("$2.00 \n");
            scanf("%d",&amt);

            if(amt == 1){
                balance = balance + 0.5;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");

            }
            if(amt == 2){
                 balance = balance + 1;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");
            }
            if(amt == 3){
                 balance = balance + 1.5;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");
            }
            if(amt == 4){
                 balance = balance + 2;
                printf("Transaction Successful \n");
            }

        }
        if(mainmenu == 2){
            printf("\n");
            printf("Balance = %d",balance,"\n");
        }
        if(mainmenu == 3){
            printf("No Transaction History At The Moment");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your first code generates 4 compiler warnings, and 3 for the second. for example it tells you that `balance = balance + 0.5;` is faulty in both codes, because `balance` is `int`.

Comment: One thing that compiler does not warn of, is your invitation to enter a fraction of a dollar as in `printf("$0.50 \n");` yet the input is `scanf("%d",&amt);`

Comment: @WeatherVane I was showing the O.P. the options he had and how it would be implemented into his code. I was not showing him how to fix his faulty code. That would be left up to him unless they asked another question specifically about those errors. Please re-read the question, and re-read my answer.

Comment: I know you mean well, but the complement of the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the **tried and tested** answer, or if you want to avoid repeating the OP's mistakes, provide a minimal answer which addresses the issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane So in the future, do you suggest I only include examples like my first 4 code snippets to keep it minimal and complete?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is probably just to use a while loop in this case.

```
while(1){
  //mainmenu here
  printf("4. Exit Program");
  scanf("%d", &mainmenu);

  //if statements/functions here
}
```

This would require you to add in a fourth option in order to exit out of the while loop, so it doesn't run endlessly (you could also use other methods to know when to exit). A good aspect of this is if they accidentally put in something invalid such as 5 or 7, it doesn't cause any bugs but rather just runs the loop again.

Keep in mind that you'd have to put all your if statements within the while loop, or put them in a different function and call that function after you get the user's input.

P.S. Unrelated but switch statements would probably be a bit easier than if else statements here. They're not necessary but could make your life a little easier.